# Need help playing Minecraft multiplayer on 2 Ipads

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to play Minecraft multiplayer on 2 Ipads. However, I can not update my minecraft. Is there still anyway we can play Minecraft multiplayer without the same versions?

Comment: Don't just randomly tag your question, the tagging system exists for a reason

Answer (score 1):

No, if the two ipads have different versions then they cannot play online together. Some features would be missing from one and would crash the game and corrupt all save data.